# Validating forms with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 function validateText1() {
    var txt = document.getElementById("Surname");
    var a = txt.value.search(/^[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/);
    if (a != 0) {
        alert("Invalid Text.\n")

        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
```

I came across this validation form, but I don't understand why is it `a!=0`, shouldn't it be `a==0`, since a number, representing the position of the first occurrence of the specified search value, or `-1` is if no match is found.

Comment: `0` would be the first index. the search looks from start to finish, so the only values you should expect are `-1` and `0`. the first condition looks for invalid, so `!= 0` and `== -1` would both be correct. `== 0` would not be.

Comment: If it doesn't find a match at the beginning of the string, it's invalid.

Comment: It seems like you're reading the whole thing backwards. When `a != 0` there's no match, and it reports "Invalid text".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically the search function tries to find text in a string, and returns the index of the first occurrence of the string.

For example:

```
var txt = "This is a funny string";

var resultIndex = txt.search("funny");

// resultIndex will return 10
```

If it is not found, it will return -1.

It should really be if (a >= 0), but the above will work too.

Comment: It requires the match to be at the beginning of the string, so `> 0` would not be valid.

Comment: It would be valid if your validation just wanted the word anywhere in the input. If validatiom required the input to start with `funny` you wouldn't use `>=`.

Comment: Of course, a regular expression that begins with `^` can never match anywhere other than at location `0`, so either way would work.

Answer (score 0):

It's `a != 0` because it's testing for a *failing* search, which is when it reports "Invalid input" and returns `false`. `a == 0` would mean that the search found a match, and in that case the input is valid and it returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The search indicates it will return the index at which position the match starts, so if it doesn't start at 0 it means a special character is used.

Altho I would never use this to validate my forms. Matching names is pretty hard.